# Vulkan incompatible driver error with proprietary Nvidia 358 driver

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, vulkan

I am attempting to install LunarG on my Ubuntu 15.10 system.  I have a GTX 750 card and I am using the Nvidia 358.16 proprietary driver.  Everything installs alright but when I run vulkaninfo, I get the error message;

```
brian@brian-MS-7699:~/VulkanSDK/1.0.3.1/examples$ vulkaninfo
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan API Version: 1.0.3

INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_draw_state.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_image.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_object_tracker.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_param_checker.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_device_limits.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_vktrace_layer.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_mem_tracker.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_unique_objects.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_threading.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_api_dump.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_screenshot.json, version "1.0.0"
INFO: [loader] Code 0 : Found manifest file /etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/VkLayer_swapchain.json, version "1.0.0"
Cannot create Vulkan instance.
/home/jeremy/Development/LunarG/Vulkan/LinuxSDK/LoaderAndValidationLayers/demos/vulkaninfo.c:691: failed with VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
```

Is this driver the correct one for Vulkan?  I used to have 361 but I uninstalled it because Steam and other OpenGL apps were throwing OpenGL exceptions.

Comment: The NVIDIA website says that 355.00.28 includes beta support for Vulkan. https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver I don't know if later releases include it as well. Since both 358.16 and 361.28 are stable releases I would actually doubt it.

Comment: SteamOS, a debian OS, got Vulkan support from Valve like day or so after Vulkan came out.  I wonder what driver they have.  I installed mine via the Ubuntu Nvidia driver repo.  I tried to run 361 but I kept getting openGL errors from my Ubuntu steam client when opening it so I guess they are not using 361.  358 works fine.